# Release Iframe after response.rediect

Tags: html, iframe

I'm using iframe with 2 frames setup.  This is all data I'm working with.  On the top frame I have a save button.  When pressed I call another html that does some data work and then does a response.redirect to another html.  When I do this it correctly goes to that page.  However, the lower frame is still visible.

Any idea how to better deal with us or simply just release the lower frame?

TIA.

Comment: Here's what I've done and I'm not getting any results:

Comment: main page - <iframe scrolling="no" noresize target="middle" src="<%=JustPath(oProp.ScriptPath)+[/MainRecord.html?id=]+tmpid"%> name="top" height="62%" class="auto-style1" style="width: 100%">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe> 
<iframe scrolling="no" noresize target="middle" src="<%=JustPath(oProp.ScriptPath)+[/ContribSummary.html?id=]+tmpid"%>  name="lower" style="width: 100%; height: 35%">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe> 
<script type = "text/javascript" >
element = document.getElementById("lower");
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Iframe from the DOM, or hide it using `display:none`.

`element = document.getElementById("element");` <-- this is the wrapper for your Iframe

```
document.removeChild(element);
```

Comment: Please see this for follow up - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299542/release-iframe-after-response-rediect-part-2