# Release Iframe after response.rediect part 2

Tags: html, iframe

I've messed up my main question so I here I go again.

I have a mainrecord.html that uses iframe to display 2 html - top and lower.  On the top html page I have a save button.  This save button does some data work and then goes to a different html.  The problem is the lower iframe is still there.  Here is what I have in the mainrecord.html:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" noresize target="middle" src="<%=JustPath(oProp.ScriptPath)+[/top.html?id=]+tmpid"%> name="top" height="62%" class="auto-style1" style="width: 100%">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe> 
<iframe scrolling="no" noresize target="middle" src="<%=JustPath(oProp.ScriptPath)+[/lower.html?id=]+tmpid"%>  name="lower" style="width: 100%; height: 35%">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe> 
<script type = "text/javascript" >
element = document.getElementById("lower");
</script>
```

In the top.html there is a save button that goes to a saverecord.html.  I do some data work and then I do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.removeChild(element);

</script>
<%   oResponse.Redirect(JUSTPATH(oProp.ScriptPath)+[/viewrecords.html])%>
```

It correctly displays viewrecords.html.  However, the iframe containing lower.html is still there.

Any suggestions?

TIA.

Comment: You didn't vote for or select an answer from your previous question. Why should anyone help you this time?

Comment: I apologize.  I was trying to respond to the previous answer and it just got all messed up.  So, please, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to a wrapping element in your JS to remove this Iframe.

```
<div class="frame2">
<iframe scrolling="no" noresize target="middle" src=""..."  name="lower" style="width: 100%; height: 35%">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe>
</div>
```

JS

```
element = document.getElementById("frame2"); <-- this is the wrapper for your Iframe
document.removeChild(element);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not quite there yet, but I'm on the right track.